# Create a new arrangement of objects and group repeating objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I have an array of objects like this

```
[
 { id: 1, note: "TEST", member_id: 1, updated_at: "2021-04-08T15:59:08.210754", product_id: 1,
 product: { id: 1, name: "Testing",},},
 {id: 2, note: "", member_id: 1, updated_at: "2021-04-08T18:07:19.712304", product_id: 5,
 product: { id: 5, name: "Insurance"}, },
 { id: 3, note: "One note", member_id: 1, updated_at: "2021-04-08T18:11:26.444726", product_id: 5, 
 product: { id: 5, name: "Insurance" },},
{ id: 4, note: "sadad", member_id: 1, updated_at: "2021-04-08T18:28:59.8435", product_id: 5, product: 
 { id: 5, name: "Insurance" }, },
];
```

I have to represent it in a table where it can be grouped by product name and the number of objects that have the same product is counted as well as the last update of any of them is shown.

It should look like this
[image]

Try to use reduce but I could not advance much because I did not understand it and I used grouby with lodash but I could not advance more than that

I need it to stay like this

```
[
 {product: "Insurance", 
 quantity: 3, 
 updated_at: "2021-04-08", 
 sales: [ 
         { id: 2, 
           note: "", 
           member_id: 1, 
           updated_at: "2021-04-08", 
           product_id: 5
         }, 
         { id: 3, 
           note: "One note", 
           member_id: 1, 
           updated_at: "2021-04-08", 
           product_id: 5
         }, 
         { id: 4, 
           note: "sadad", 
           member_id: 1, 
           updated_at: "2021-04-08",
           product_id: 5
         }
        ]
  },
  {product: "Testing", 
   quantity: 1, 
   updated_at: "2021-04-08", 
   sales: [ 
           {id: 1, 
            note: "TEST", 
            member_id: 1, 
            updated_at: "2021-04-08", 
            product_id: 1,} 
          ]},
]
```

I tried to use reduce but it was not what I expected and I did not understand it much either

```
array.reduce((acc, it) => {
acc[it.product.name] = acc[it.product.name] + 1 || 1;
return acc;
}, {});
```

Comment: Maybe this will be of help to you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40774697/how-to-group-an-array-of-objects-by-key

Comment: you haven't shown any attempt, please provide it. Aslo please provide the final JSON structure you want

Comment: I already completed the missing data, could you guide me how to solve the problem? @EugenSunic

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Most efficient method to groupby on an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446511/most-efficient-method-to-groupby-on-an-array-of-objects)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this, it will should give you the desired output.

```js
const list = [{
    id: 1,
    note: "TEST",
    member_id: 1,
    updated_at: "2021-04-08T15:59:08.210754",
    product_id: 1,
    product: {
      id: 1,
      name: "Testing",
    },
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    note: "",
    member_id: 1,
    updated_at: "2021-04-08T18:07:19.712304",
    product_id: 5,
    product: {
      id: 5,
      name: "Insurance"
    },
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    note: "One note",
    member_id: 1,
    updated_at: "2021-04-08T18:11:26.444726",
    product_id: 5,
    product: {
      id: 5,
      name: "Insurance"
    },
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    note: "sadad",
    member_id: 1,
    updated_at: "2021-04-08T18:28:59.8435",
    product_id: 5,
    product: {
      id: 5,
      name: "Insurance"
    },
  },
];

const result = list.reduce((acc, x) => {
  const index = acc.findIndex(obj => obj.product === x.product.name);
  const salesObj = {
    id: x.id,
    note: x.note,
    member_id: x.member_id,
    updated_at: x.updated_at,
    product_id: x.product_id
  };
  if (index < 0) {
    acc = [...acc, {
      product: x.product.name,
      quantity: 1,
      updated_at: x.updated_at,
      sales: [salesObj]
    }];
    return acc;
  }
  acc[index].updated_at = x.updated_at;
  acc[index].quantity++;
  acc[index].sales.push(salesObj);
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result)
```

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for, I wanted to ask you how I could put the last update_at of the salts in the new object?

Comment: which new object?

Comment: {"product": "Insurance",
    "quantity": 3,
    "updated_at": "2021-04-08", sales: [{...}]}

Comment: @JorgeBarcos update then the existing object to get the latest value/update like this 
 ```acc[index].updated_at = x.updated_at; ```Added the change, check it out

Answer (score 2):

```
const sales = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "note": "TEST",
    "member_id": 1,
    "updated_at": "2021-04-08T15:59:08.210754",
    "product_id": 1,
    "product": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Testing"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "note": "",
    "member_id": 1,
    "updated_at": "2021-04-08T18:07:19.712304",
    "product_id": 5,
    "product": {
      "id": 5,
      "name": "Insurance"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "note": "One note",
    "member_id": 1,
    "updated_at": "2021-04-08T18:11:26.444726",
    "product_id": 5,
    "product": {
      "id": 5,
      "name": "Insurance"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "note": "sadad",
    "member_id": 1,
    "updated_at": "2021-04-08T18:28:59.8435",
    "product_id": 5,
    "product": {
      "id": 5,
      "name": "Insurance"
    }
  }
];


const newObject = sales.reduce((allProducts, singleSale) => {
  if(allProducts.has(singleSale.product.name)){

    const product = allProducts.get(singleSale.product.name);
    
    allProducts.set(singleSale.product.name, {
      ...product,
      quantity: product.sales.length + 1,
      sales: [...product.sales, singleSale]
    });

  } else {
    allProducts.set(singleSale.product.name, {
      product: singleSale.product.name,
      quantity: 1, 
      sales: [singleSale]
    })
  }
  
  return allProducts;
}, new Map());

console.log([...newObject.values()])
```

https://jsbin.com/govocoyeri/edit?js,console

This should give you the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

Use `_.gropyBy` to group the items, and use `_.toPairs` to get key-value pair of an object and then use `map` to customize the objects in a group

here `list` is the input array

```
var result = _.toPairs(_.groupBy(list, 'product.name'))
 .map(([product, sales]) => {
    const quantity = sales.length;
        return {
            product, 
            quantity, 
            updated_at: sales[quantity-1].updated_at, 
            sales: sales.map(item => _.omit(item, 'product')) 
        }
    });
console.log(result)
```